# VLC Stream URL not working

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

When I try to open an URL on VLC it doesn't work.

Here is the command I'm using:

```
vlc youtube.com/watch?v=POCngEpkOLI VLC media player 2.0.3 Twoflower (revision 2.0.2-93-g77aa89e) [0x15960a8] main libvlc : Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'vclc' to use vlc without interface. [ox19737d8] gnutls tls client error : A TLS packet with unexpected length was received. [ox1957f28] main access error : Read error : Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Does it show a blank screen? How about an error message?

Comment: On VLC I don't have any video and on the terminal it says :
[ox19737d8] gnutls tls client error : A TLS packet with unexpected length was received. 
[ox1957f28] main access error : Read error : Connection reset by peer

Comment: Ok, I don't know if it'll help, but VLC requires a CA-Certificate file to be able to validate an https connection. See the answer posted [here](http://superuser.com/a/719487/107240)

Comment: Still not working. I used the solution in the link but it's not a certificate problem, the CA seems to be installed

Comment: With some live streamins like [this one of FreeCodeCamp](https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp/live) return `adaptive demux: Encountered discontinuity` and then `ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0`. Some others works just fine.